# DB2 how to sum two column from two different table

Tags: sql, db2, sum

```
Select sum(amt) as totalA from tableA where id>10;
Select sum(amount) as totalB from tableB where people = 'JOSH';
```

What is the best way if the objective is to have `sum(totalA + totalB)`?

Comment: are you allowed to use T-SQL?

Comment: @almasshaikh: there is no "T-SQL" in DB2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(total) from
(
    select sum(amt) as total from tableA where id>10
    union all
    select sum(amount) from tableB where people = 'JOSH'
) as q
```